# Can a single chunk be shared among multiple dbspaces?

Tags: database, informix

If a dbspace fills out then we add a chunk to that dbspace. My question is can a single chunk be shared among multiple dbspaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single chunk, defined as a combination of file/device name plus starting offset and size, can only belong to a single dbspace.  It must not overlap with any other chunk.  However, disjoint sections of a single device can be allocated to separate dbspaces.

Comment: thanks a lot mr.leffler, I have one more query i.e., one of my databases got corrupt , I am not able to connect to it and not able to drop it too. because of the following errors: "311: Cannot open system catalog (systables).
135: ISAM error: TBLspace does not exist " please help me with this.

Comment: That's a full scale disaster. I hope you keep good backups and know how to use them.  If you have Tech Support, contact them right away.  If you don't, recovery from backup is likely to be your main choice, IMO.   You should run `oncheck` on the system with various sets of options to see how serious the problem is.  It may be able to recover things for you.  Otherwise, ask at the [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/), the International Informix User Group.  They have mailing lists you could join to ask.  SO is not good for Tech Support crises.

Comment: hi Mr.leffler , I have one more doubt i.e., is it possible to add chunks of  both raw and cooked type to single dbspace? please clear my doubt.

Comment: Yes.  A single dbspace can contain a mixture of raw and cooked chunks.  Whether that's a good idea is a separate debate, but it is technically doable without problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Leffler